# Solving Knapsack 0/1 problem using Substitution method

Tags: algorithm

I want to solve knapsack problem with Substitution method, I can't find the therom of knapsack problem through its algorithm so I need help for finding the therom of knapsack problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate a bit more about what you're trying to do? I've seen the term "substitution method" mostly in reference to big-O analysis rather than algorithm design. Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by "finding the theorem of knapsack problem" and tell us what you've done so far?

Comment: Finding the therom of knapsack problem means that I want solve knapsack problem with Substitution method and in substitution method we have a question that we can solve with this method and find the time complexity of a algorithm  like if we solve the merge sort from substitution method the first we make this question T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n through merge sort algorithm and then we solve that using substitution method, so I can't create this question through kanpsack algorithm.